# Time based switch in Twig

Tags: date, time, switch-statement, twig

I currently have a php switch statement to display content at a certain time. I want to be able to rewrite this as a twig statement.

The php switch is this:

```
switch($day){
        case "Sun":
         if ($time >= 00 && $time <= 12){
            CODE...;    
        }elseif ($time >= 12 && $time <= 14){
            CODE...;
        }elseif ($time >= 14 && $time <= 2359){
            CODE...;
        }
        break;

        cases for every day....

}
```

Obviously I call the day and time with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$day = date('D');
$time = date('H:i');
```

I understand how twig switches work but I'm confused on how I could attach time and day variables.

Hope you can help!

Comment: twig does not have a `switch`. I think u'r better off with just extending twig and add a function or filter depending on the desired output

Comment: Twig does have a switch: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/switch.html

Comment: That is `craftcms` not `twig`. See [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/) for all the existings `tags`. If you are using `craft` you should update the question and add that tag.

Comment: Ah! Doh! Ok, I'll need to write this as an if statement. Thanks.